# How widespread is the use of hexagonal architecture (ports and adapters architecture)?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, hexagonal-architecture

We are discussing the adoption of [hexagonal architecture (ports and adapters architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) in our team.

Sometimes I use the rate of adoption as one rough metric about how beneficial a certain practice is. However, I can't find any hints about how widespread the use of hexagonal architecture is.

Do you have any hints about how prevalent hexagonal architecture is in software projects? Is it used in big tech companies too?

Comment: Your question seems misguided because the use of an architectural style (and most other patterns in general) is not just a question of widespread usage, but mostly whether it makes sense in your context. There are many contexts where hexagonal architecture would not be better than another architecture, regardless of its adoption rate in the industry.

Comment: @VincentSavard - your point is well taken.  But I'd still like to see the estimate the OP desires.  I for one had never heard of hexagonal architecture _except for the couple of dozen questions about it here on the SoftEng stack!_

Comment: @davidbak There are multiple names for this architecture (or at least, a few very similar architectures). It is very common in the DDD world where isolating the business logic from technical and infrastructure details is important.

Comment: The description of "hexagonal" seems to be applicable to any level of abstraction, and so broad that it reads more like a general design principle than an architecture.   It seems only to describe using well-defined boundaries (interfaces, which it calls "ports" and could be almost anything), with loosely-coupled components that communicate using those interfaces,  yet those things are fundamental ingredients for isolation and testability (which tend to be required by nearly all but the smallest software projects, and therefore would be present in most larger, well-architected systems).

Answer (score 3):

Check out google trends

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=Hexagonal%20architecture,onion%20architecture

Occasionally you see a paper on the adoption of a methodology or practice in industry but I am always very skeptical of them.

I think in practice any large system will have a combination of architectural influences rather than following a single pattern exclusively.

If you were to look at systems without knowing the motivation of the designer I doubt you could tell the difference between hexagonal and onion for example.

However, having said that, from my own experience I would say that hexagonal is a fairly well known and "popular" architectural style. The arguments around it seem to focus on whether its original, rather than whether the basic ideas are good. But being popular as in known or liked, doesn't mean it get applied in practice.

Comment: Hexagonal is clearly the oldest and Clean the newest. But since all 3 are the same idea, with different names for their parts, it doesn't matter which you pick. But Clean Architecture is currently [wining the meaningless trend war](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=Hexagonal%20architecture,onion%20architecture,clean%20architecture). What does matter is which one has the explanation you find easiest to understand. Because only understanding it will tell you if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that microservices are based on the ideas of hexagonal architecture, it is a very popular architecture nowadays:

> The microservice architecture is also an architectural style. (...)
> Each service has its own logical view architecture which is typically a hexagonal architecture 
> - Chris Richardson, *Microservice patterns*, p.40

If you climb the levels of abstractions and look a little bit wider, you may also consider that Onion Architecture and Clean Architecture are specializations of the more general hexagonal architecture. In which case every implementations of the first would also be an implementation of the latter.  HA would then perhaps still not be dominant, but significant in any case.